# Does Microsoft Security Essentials Shut Down Illegal Copies of Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ms-security-essentials, wga

Well, this is a theoretical question of course. I got this from the installation agreement:

> a. The software may cause the operating system software to conduct **validation checks** of your operating system software **from time to time**, depending upon your specific operating system.
>
> b.Validation verifies that your computer’s operating system has been **activated** and is **properly licensed**. Validation also permits you to use certain features of the operating system software or to obtain additional benefits.

It seems reasonable that they would want to do it. Has anyone tried installing on orbit converted rtm ?

Comment: I don't know that it's entirely theoretical.  There are two reasons a validation check might fail.  First, the OS could be an illegitimate copy, unlicensed, and/or unactivated.  Second, it could be mistakenly identified as such.  Microsoft has had false positives in the past, and they might have more in the future.

Answer (score 2):

This link may be helpful. It appears Win7 will treat non-genuine copies the same as Vista SP1 does. You will be nagged but not disabled.

http://blogs.msdn.com/wga/archive/2009/02/23/windows-7-beta.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It will only install on an activated copy of Windows, and I suppose it is possible (but no way confirmed) that from time to time if there are product updates (talking about the actual engine, not definition updates), it will require re-checking that your machine passes activation.

That being said, I do not think that it will ever de activate your copy of Windows.

I hate the whole WGA thing, however I think Microsoft are to lenient now on pirates, the worst that will happen is you get a 10 second warning and can use your machine like normal - with a few pop ups from time to time.

Anyway, I hope this is general knowledge and you do not have a dodgy copy of Windows!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title (I don't have a cracked version to try it on), no, it shouldn't shut it down by itself (who knows what Microsoft will do if they find out you have a pirated copy though...).  The validation check is there to encourage you to use legal copies of Windows.  Microsoft stopped being quite so militant (although I really couldn't say I blamed them...) about pirated software and instead made you validate to get some of their free utilities.  A lot of nonessential but cool (powertoys, etc) utilities and optional updates (critical updates and security patches don't require validation) require you validate as well.  It really is nothing more than a way of checking to see if you deserve a reward for playing nice.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe the RC restarts when its expired... could be that